# Choosing color in matplotlib contour maps

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Hello all of matplotlib experts! I have not found description in matplotlib examples of how can I set which colours I want each area to be. Is it possible to set the colours myself instead of matplotlib automatically assign them?

The contour map that I obtained so far looks like this:

[image: Contour map to be modified]

Any other recommendations on how to produce readable contour maps will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html). You can set up your own colormap colors like this:

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'])
```

You can also select from the existing [colormap options](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

Comment: I get error message when trying to use this line:>>> CS = plt.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ListedColormap'
>>>

Comment: I pulled that from the first link. plt != mpl.